# app/assets/javascripts - only .coffee files are being run. Not .js files. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought I could just go into application.js and do this

```
//= require books.js
```

or

```
//= require books
```

But nothing I write in `books.js` works. I have to write coffeescript in the existing `books.coffee` file, which me no like.

Why?

Comment: Do you have a books.js.coffee file?

Comment: no, the generator gave me books.coffee, so that's what I used. Will renaming it allow me to write pure JS?

Comment: Oops, I think that's what I meant. I want to say that priority is given to .coffee if you have coffee-rails in your gemfile, but I'm not certain. Remove the .coffee file, and try again.